# Laravel 5.5 LengthAwarePaginator is converted to a collection once passed to a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

im using laravel v 5.5
i have the following Method

```
public function AllNotification ()
{
    $data[ 'notifications' ] = Notification::ThisUser ()->latest ()->paginate ( 10 );
    return view ('Notifications.allNotifications',$data);
}
```

and if i `dd($data);`
this is the result

[image: dd resukt]

when i show the view and print the content of `{{dd($notifications)}}`
this is what is shown and the `$notifications->links()` is gone duo to that

[image: view dd of notifications]

im not sure what's happening as on all other methods its working fine

Comment: why are you using lengthawarepaginator on a single model? Can't get the point.

Comment: single model...?

Comment: Strange, have you tried not using `$data` and instead `$notifications = Notification::ThisUser...` and return your view using `->with('notifications', $notifications);`. Shouldn't make a difference, but who knows

Comment: i tried compact('notifications') , with the same behavior , i will try with() now

Comment: @kerbholz , yes it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paginate a standard Laravel Collection in your views you can add this macro code to the `AppServiceProvider` class within the `boot()` function:

```
    /**
     * Paginate a standard Laravel Collection.
     *
     * @param int $perPage
     * @param int $total
     * @param int $page
     * @param string $pageName
     * @return array
     */
    Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
        $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
            $total ?: $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page,
            [
                'path'     => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'pageName' => $pageName
            ]
        );
    });
```

Comment: shouldn't this happen by default since i'm calling the paginate method?

Comment: Yes. You can update the default parameters if needed in the call. In addition you will need to use the `slice` function to get the correct data based on the current page and the page size.